# Parameters. Only show in main dataset

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2012

I have a main data set called "IncomeRecievedGeneralNeeds". This is what is used on the main report. This includes a field called "Scheme"

I have created a new dataset called "scheme" and a parameter called scheme, but I only want the scheme parameter to show schemes that are in the main dataset.At present it is showing me schemes that are not in the main dataset.

The Scheme code is here -

```
SELECT DISTINCT  loc.scheme AS 'Scheme'
FROM    ih_location loc
```

The IncomeRecievedGeneralNeeds code is here  -

```
SELECT DISTINCT  trans.tncy_sys_ref AS 'TncySysRef'
                ,ten.tenancy_ref AS 'TenancyRef'
                ,trans.created_date AS 'TransactionCreatedDate'
                ,MHS.startdate AS 'StartofWeekDate'
                ,MHS.enddate AS 'EndofWeekDate'
                ,MHS.financialyear AS 'TransactionFiscalYear'
                ,MHS.monthname AS 'TransactionFiscalMonthName'
                ,MHS.month AS 'TransactionFiscalMonth'
                ,MHS.week AS 'TransactionFiscalWeek'
                ,CONCAT('Week ',
                         MHS.week,
                        ' (',
                        CONVERT(varchar(11),MHS.startdate,103),
                        '-',
                        CONVERT(varchar(11),MHS.enddate,103),
                        ')'
                        ) AS 'TransactionFiscalWeekWithDates'
                ,trans.comment_ AS 'TransactionComment'
                ,trans.trans_amt AS 'TransactionAmount'
                ,CASE WHEN trans.account_type IN ('IN','LI') Then 'Income'
                        WHEN trans.account_type = 'HB' Then 'HousingBenefit'
                        ELSE '' END AS 'AccountType'
                ,trans.account_type
                ,ACC.description AS 'AccountCode'
                ,loc.scheme AS 'Scheme'
                ,loc.mgt_area AS 'Management Area'
                ,loc.location_type AS 'Location Type'
                ,loct.description AS 'Location Type Description'
                ,ten.tncy_start AS 'TenancyStartDate'
                ,ten.tncy_end AS 'TenancyEndDate'
                ,CASE WHEN ten.tncy_end IS NULL 
                    OR TRANS.created_date < ten.tncy_end 
                    THEN 'Current' ELSE 'Former' END AS 'IncomeTenancyStatus'
                ,ten.tncy_status AS 'TenanacyStatus'
                ,CASE WHEN ten.tncy_status = 'FOR' THEN LOC.former_arrs_ofcr ELSE loc.arrears_ofcr END AS 'OfficerCode' 


FROM    [dbo].[re_tncy_trans] trans
    INNER JOIN  
        re_tenancy ten
    ON trans.tncy_sys_ref = ten.tncy_sys_ref
    INNER JOIN
        re_tncy_place tenpl
    ON  TEN.tncy_sys_ref = tenpl.tncy_sys_ref
    INNER JOIN
        ih_location loc
    ON  tenpl.place_ref = loc.place_ref
    INNER JOIN
        [dbo].[re_accounts] acc
    ON
    trans.account_code = ACC.account_code
    AND trans.account_type = acc.account_type
    INNER JOIN
    [mhsInsight].[dbo].[mhs_month_week] mhs
    ON trans.created_date BETWEEN mhs.startdate AND MHS.enddate
    INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[ih_location_type] AS loct
    ON loc.location_type = LOCT.location_type


WHERE trans.account_type IN ('IN','HB','LI')
AND MHS.startdate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-04-07 00:00:00', 102)
and loc.place_ref <> '9999999999'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your parameter query, use the same FROM and WHERE clause that you use in your main query, and you will only get the same Schemes that you have in your main dataset.

Comment: I tried that already - but think that is what is making my report run really slowly in that it takes a long while for my parameters to even show before I can select them. It does work but was wondering if there was a better way of doing it?

Comment: Well you know your database better than I do, so maybe you use that knowledge to eliminate some joins and filters that are not really needed to get the results you want.   Also you could try indexes to improve the performance of the query.   But no, there isn't a whole different better approach; this is the way to do it.